# Internet explorer 10 converts Cafe to Café - how to disable?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Is it possible to disable this feature? The web page I am visiting requires that I only use ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

Backspace and it should obey the second time.